# Why isnt discord.py member.join working for me?

Tags: python, discord.py

i want to get the guild that a member just joined so i know where to send the message to.

ex:

-member joins guild: spaceDruids

-bot sends member a message on guild spaceDruids

the problem is that when the `on_member_join()` event fires, `member.guild` does not return a guild. its blank.

heres my code to take a look:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'token here'

intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to discord!!!')
    
    
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    print('called')
    print(member)
    print(member.guild)
    ##await guild.text_channels[0].send('Welcome @{member.name}!!!')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

i've looked at the discord documentation and i've done everything it wants!

i have the required intents in my code: `intents.members = True`
which discord says i need:
[image]

so why doesnt member.guild return anything like it says it should? it just returns blank. no error though
[image]

Comment: How do you know that they're in a guild and that data is supposed to be returned? What other data does the `member` have?

Comment: on_member_join() returns a member when they've joined a guild. so for on_member_join() to even fire the member has to be a part of at least one guild. more specifically on_member_join() only fires when a member has joined the guild that my bot is a part of. data is suppose to be returned because the discord documentation says that on_member_join(member) returns the member who joined. the documentation also says that member.guild should return the guild or guilds the member is a part of.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Discord requires `intents.guilds = True` to return `member.guild`

I don't see that as a requirement anywhere in the documentation but I figured it out.

Documentation says `on_member_join(member)` requires `intents.members = True` to return the member. what it does not say is that to get `member.guild` from `member` in `on_member_join(member)` that you also need `intents.guilds`

In hindsight, I guess it's a little obvious it *might* need that but it doesn't explicitly say that anywhere in documentation.

Comment: I believe this is happening because the bot won't cache any of the information about any guilds unless the guilds intent is set, so that information isn't available when you go looking for it. This is kind of tangentially mentioned in the Intents documentation, but I agree it isn't very clear